# Swift/Sprite-kit Adding a static hud that is always at the top and bottom, with the moveable game in the middle?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7

I have been playing around trying to learn spritekit in xcode7. So far I have a level that is larger than the screen, a hero the I can move around and a camera that follows the hero as he moves off the the viewable screen area. Next I'm trying to create a hud at the top and bottom of the screen. The bottom one would be where the joystick/buttons live.

I tried something like this:

```
let hud = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height * 0.05))
hud.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
hud.position = CGPointMake(0, (self.view?.bounds.height)! - hud.size.height)
self.addChild(hud)
```

But this puts a black view at the top of my level and I can only see it if I walk my hero up there.  That means if I move it to the bottom, as soon as my hero walks up the joystick and buttons will be off the screen.

Can anyone please provide any direction on how I can add huds to sprite-kit that are always at the top and bottom of the viewable area, while still allowing the hero to move around the level?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the HUD as a child of the scene, then add the world as a child of the scene too. The character must be a child of the world.

This way, the character can move around the world and then the world can be moved on the scene so the character could be visible, without messing with the HUD.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

This should move your hud (suppose is a `SKNode`) from the origin `anchorPoint` (0.5,0.5) of the camera to `CGPoint.zero` always visible:

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        hud.position = CGPoint(x:-self.frame.midX,y:-self.frame.midY)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to doing this, one is to add `UIButton`s to your view which will always appear on the top, the other (which I commonly use) is dynamically setting the position of the hud based off of the anchor point of the scene.

The first way is pretty simple, just create the `UIButton`s and `UILabel`s in Interface Builder and they should be on top of your scene (you may need to mess around with view layer numbers to get it appearing above though).

The other way is to put some code in the `didSimulatePhysics` method (which will only be called after the update, and after the physics have been simulated).  Basically, doing what you are doing, and setting the position of the `hud` to the scene's `anchorPoint` multiplied by the width and height of the scene.  Something like this (my Swift is a little rough):

```
let x = (((-self.scene.anchorPoint.x) * self.frame.size.x) + anyOffsetRequired.x)
let y = (((-self.scene.anchorPoint.y) * self.frame.size.y) + anyOffsetRequired.y)
hud.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
```

The `-` on the `anchorPoint` is due to how moving the scene's `anchorPoint` works (going right requires negative, going down requires positive).  `anyOffsetRequired` is just a `CGPoint` that allows you to set the offset, you may or may not need it in your case.

Comment: So has a quick test I used didSimulatePhysics along with the anchorPoint to place the joystick in it's normal position at the bottom left with:  

    `override func didSimulatePhysics() {  
        
        let x = ((self.scene?.anchorPoint.x)! * self.frame.size.width) + 100  
        let y = ((self.scene?.anchorPoint.y)! * self.frame.size.height) + 100  
          
        joyStick.base.position = CGPointMake(x, y)  
        
        
    }`  

But has soon as I moved away from the area the joystick scrolled off the screen and disappeared

Comment: Okay, maybe you need to remove the` !` (things may have changed around in Swift)?  Also, what is the base parameter?

Comment: I can't remove the `!`'s. xcode won't compile without them, it's requiring that I unwrap the anchorPoints. The base is the base of the joystick, it's a two piece joyStick with a base and a ball.

Comment: Okay, the joystick makes sense (I wasn't sure if it was something special).  In the code that you posted in your comment, you did not include the `-` which I had mentioned is required due to how moving the scene's `anchorPoint` works.  I had thought that the `!` was something that did the same as `-`.  Anyway, include the negative sign (`-`), probably something like this if you need to unwrap first: `-((self.scene?.anchorPoint.<x or y>)!)` instead of the `(self.scene?.anchorPoint.x)!`

Comment: When I include the (-) it says:
Unary operator '-' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'CGFloat?'

Comment: By unwrapping scene I was able to use the (-) but the effect is the same.  I think didSimulatePhysics only gets called once, right? So if I'm setting the position there it will get set once and never get updated. All I want to do is add a hud that stays at the top or bottom of the screen that I can add things like a joystick and scorelabel to. When the player moves around the scene, the hud should remain in place, just like when you scroll around the game world in Clash of Clans

Comment: No, `didSimulatePhysics` is called every frame (after physics is calculated, which is after the `update`).  Maybe just try putting this code in `update`?  Is  the joystick moving away from you, relative to the world it is on?  And this just occurred to me, how are you moving the world around?  Is it by using the `anchorPoint` of the scene way?

Comment: I don't think I want the joystick to move around the screen, that would make it hard to use? Is there a way to make a layer above the game world that never moves? To me, that seems how clash of clans do it

Comment: @Bill  It doesn't quite work that way, at least the way I described.  Please tell me if you are moving your "world" around (basically tricking the user into thinking the camera is moving, but it is just the anchor point of the scene) kind of like Apple describes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW32).